# How to combine two rows (consisting of characters) into one

Tags: r

I am trying to combine two rows (with no row names) into one.  I know I could use aggregate if it the cells numerical/float, or could I still use aggregate on characters?

[example of what the two rows look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/norNS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try again:

Let's create a matrix along the lines of what you've got:

```
new <- matrix( data = NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 2 )
new[1,] <- c( "Tue", "Wed" )
new[2,] <- c( 1, 2 )
```

Now let's create a new vector by combining the two rows we've got:

```
newer <- paste0( new[1,], new[2,] )
```

Now we can bind that to the bottom of our matrix:

```
new <- rbind( new, newer )
```

Does that do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a similar thing here, using the "day.of.week" function* to take a column of dates, and return a column of "day of the week":

```
output$day <- ifelse( is.na( output$date ), NA,
                           day.of.week( as.integer( substr( as.character( output$date ), 6, 7 ) ),
                                        as.integer( substr( as.character( output$date ), 9, 10 ) ),
                                        as.integer( substr( as.character( output$date ), 1, 4 ) )
                           ) + 1L )
day.values <- c( "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" )
output$day <- day.values[ output$day ]
```

Note I've put it into an ifelse, in order to avoid trying to calculate day of the week for empty or NA fields.

Basically, the "day.of.week" function in chron (so make sure you're running the chron package) returns a value between 1 and 7 for each date. That 1-7 value is then used to extract the text value for "day" from the list I've made called "day.values".

- Note the input to "day.of.week" is in the format (year, month, day) ie for April 26, 2016:

  ```
  day.of.week( 2016, 04, 26 )
  ```

  My code is taking a date input in "Date" format, meaning it looks like:

  ```
  2016-04-26
  ```

Comment: Wait, I've just re-read your question, and I may have answered what I _thought_  you were asking, but was in fact something entirely different. Sorry if that's the case, I got confused :P

Comment: It is cool.  My question was kind of confusing (auto correct on my phone -_- ).  But I already can tell that you made a new column.  But you did give me an idea to run with.  Thank you.